# Google Play Store: Error No. 905

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, motorola-moto-g, system-error

I have Motorola Moto G XT1033, rooted. I installed CM12 Nightly. I am not able to download apps sized more than 200 MB from Play Store. No option to uninstall updates of Play Store.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest play store apk from androidpolice and install it over the system apk. Check if it works.
Alternatively, you can also try uninstalling updates of google play services and check.